# I want my program to sort the value 'score' highest to lowest

Tags: python, sorting

```
import random #This will import the random function, allowing me to ask the user random questions
import sys #This will allow me to exit the program within the program
score = 0
print ("What is your name?")
name = input()
if name=="" or name==" " or name.isdigit():
    print("Error")
    sys.exit()
print("Hello",name,", are you in class 1,2 or 3?")
print("\nEnter '1' for class 1, enter '2' for class 2 and enter '3' for class     3")
class_name = (input())
if class_name=="" or class_name==" ":
    print("Error")
    sys.exit()

print ('\nYou will be asked 10 questions involving addition, subtraction and multiplicaton')

for x in range(10):#Loop will reapeat 10 times

    operation2 = ['+','-','*']#These are the operations I will use
    operation = random.choice(operation2)#Randomising the operation that will be used
    num1=random.randint(1,10)#Random number 1-10
    num2=random.randint(1,10)#Random number 1-10
    num3=int(eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2)))

    print ("\n",num1,operation,num2)#Prints the question
    answer=int(input())#User input
    if answer=="" or answer==" ":
        print("Error")
        sys.exit()
    if answer == num3:
        print ("Correct")
        score += 1#Adds 1 to 'score'
    else:
        print("Incorrect")
print("\nYou scored",score,"out of 10") #This will display your final score out of 10

if class_name== '1':
    with open("Class 1 Highest Score.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines.append("{}:{}\n".format(score,name))
    lines.sort(reverse=True)
    with open("Class 1 Highest Score.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("".join(lines))

if class_name== '2':
    with open("Class 2 Highest Score.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines.append("{}:{}\n".format(score,name))
    lines.sort(reverse=True)
    with open("Class 2 Highest Score.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("".join(lines))

if class_name== '3':
    with open("Class 3 Highest Score.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    lines.append("{}:{}\n".format(score,name))
    lines.sort(reverse=True)
    with open("Class 3 Highest Score.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("".join(lines))
```

I want the program to output the results to a text file which works. And then I want it to sort it highest to lowest by score. It kind of works, basically if you score 10/10 in the quiz, in the text file it puts 10 at the bottom but apart from that it sorts it perfectly but how would I fix this issue.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: you are sorting strings which means that `'10'<'5'` since it reads it by character (ie, since `'10'` starts with `'1'` which is less than `'5'`)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  For future questions, it will really help us (and you) if you cut the question down to a [mcve].  In this case, you're satisfied with everything except how the scores get sorted.  This means that you should create a list of `lines` where you hard code 2 or 3 lines of data that aren't sorted the way you'd like, and focus your question on sorting that.  Doing so may also help you find the answer to your own questions.

Comment: There are a bunch of ways you can improve this code, first when you are dealing with numbers store them as numbers and not strings, this will make things much easier and solve your problem here. Then deal with the duplicated code to handle the different output options, this can be done in much easier way. Also you have "magic" variable throughout the code, you should change those too.

Comment: How would I make 10>5